# Why does jdb print command not when when all threads have been suspended?

Tags: java, jdb

When using JDB, why can't `print` be used even after suspending all threads?

In the below example, I've started a debugger session and have selected a thread. Initially `dump` doesn't work because the thread is not suspended. That is expected. Then, all threads are suspended with `suspend`. After this, `dump` works as expected. However, `print` still does not work. What does "Thread not suspended for method invoke" mean?

```
Thread-1[1] dump this
com.sun.jdi.IncompatibleThreadStateException
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.ThreadReferenceImpl.frameCount(ThreadReferenceImpl.java:342)
    at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.ThreadInfo.getCurrentFrame(ThreadInfo.java:221)
    at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.Commands.evaluate(Commands.java:106)
    at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.Commands.doPrint(Commands.java:1654)
    at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.Commands$3.action(Commands.java:1680)
    at com.sun.tools.example.debug.tty.Commands$AsyncExecution$1.run(Commands.java:66)
 this = null
Current thread isn't suspended.
Thread-1[1] suspend
All threads suspended.
Thread-1[1] dump this
 this = {
    testVar: 60
}
Thread-1[1] print this
com.sun.tools.example.debug.expr.ParseException: Unable to complete expression. Thread not suspended for method invoke
```

Comment: it's not clear from the question what you're actually trying to accomplish. why not just set a breakpoint, for instance?

Comment: I'm debugging an application that hangs after receiving SIGINT. There's a fair amount of logic in a shutdown hook which I believe to be responsible. I can attach to it once it's in the hung state, but then I won't be able to set a breakpoint since it's stalled (likely a deadlock). More generally though, why doesn't the `suspend` command appear to work? It says all threads are suspended, then the `print` command says the thread _isn't_ suspended.